# How to avoid the negative values in Raster extraction [ example -32767] in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation, nodata

I 'am trying get a raster values as xyz format for ground terrain analysis using QGIS software,
After extracting raster data,few cells are showing -32767 values, how to get rid of these negative values. The format is XYZ, and these were obtained from an SRTM DEM projected in UTM in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if you don’t have nodata values at those pixels?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

The [QGIS `gdal2xyz` processing tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#gdal2xyz) uses the [`gdal2xyz` GDAL commandline tool](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2xyz.html).

The QGIS tool doesn't expose all of the options you can pass to the `gdal2xyz` GDAL commandline tool.

As of GDAL 3.3, you can pass a `-skipnodata` option and the GDAL `gdal2xyz` tool will not output `nodata`.

So you could try running the GDAL `gdal2xyz` tool from the command line.

E.g.

```
gdal2xyz.py -skipnodata input_strm_dem.tif output.xyz
```

If your raster doesn't have `nodata` defined, you should be able to tell GDAL to use a specific value with the `-srcnodata` option, but as of [GDAL 3.6, this option is broken](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/7410).

E.g.

```
gdal2xyz.py -skipnodata -srcnodata -32768 input_strm_dem.tif output.xyz
gdal2xyz.py: error: argument -srcnodata/-nodatavalue: invalid Real value: '-32768'
```